# Script on Custom self hosted Agents

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I basically have a decorator injecting steps into all pipelines of an organization. This decorator runs a PowerShell script that will trigger an azure function. Within our agent pool, we have our own self-hosted custom agents. Some of those don't have PowerShell installed. How can I trigger my az function?

We do not have control over the custom agents. It is not under our belt, so we need to handle random configurations on custom agents.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you could solve this problem by installing PowerShell on your custom agents. If that's not an option, please describe _why not_

Comment: thanks, I adjusted the question.

Comment: Whats happens when you use the PowerShell@2 task? it should be downloaded to your agent when the run starts.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops

I just checked, you could also specify a demand for "PowerShell", the task then only runs on agents that satisfy the demand
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Hey, Josef thanks for taking the time to answer. The thing is that it really needs to run for all pipelines independent of their agents. But I will give a look at the first part of your answer.

Just gave a look is a no go:

Both of these shortcuts resolve to the PowerShell@2 task. powershell runs Windows PowerShell and will only work on a Windows agent. pwsh runs PowerShell Core, which must be installed on the agent or container.

Comment: I was thinking of going in the direction of creating my own agent to run this decorator but is always in a different pool of the other agents from different pipelines. Not sure if is possible to specify different agent pool on a decorator :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I resolved by converting all my PowerShell scripts to bash. Now I can script within a decorator that can run in any agent from any agent pool. The only setback is that different OS can have different bash versions and a mismatch of the code functions, so I still needed to make kind of a switch to determine what is the os and run a particular bash script.